# Share folders over a PC and virtual machine

Tags: windows-xp, directory, sharing

I have several files stored on a virtual machine that I am running on my PC, I want to simply transfer them over to the C drive on the PC however not sure how to. There is no email enabled and the virtual machine will not pick up any memory stick.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a question for Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: What virtualization software are you using (VMWare, VBox, Qemu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VMWare you can use Shared Folders between the host (your PC) and the guest machines.

For this to work, you have to install in your guest machine [VMWare Tools](http://www.vmware.com/download/packages.html). Once installed, you can configure Shared Folders.

If this doesn't work, you could always connect using a network shared folder.